# Play: does it re-render the page upon variable changes in the views?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

How often does the play render the page? Like say I have conditional as following

```
@if(viewModel.record.isRunning) {
    <h5>
        <center><i>
            <div id="database"></div>
        </i></center>
    </h5>
 }
```

If at some point `viewModel.record.isRunning` changes would it re-render/refresh the page? My observation so far is that, it doesn't update the page (which was surprising to me). If this observation is true (i.e. I don't have any other bugs), any suggestions on how to make the re-renders/update happen?

Comment: Why would you think the page gets refreshed? The rendering happens on the server side, the template engine is not a client side technology such as angular.

Answer (score 4):

It may help if you can explain why you expect the page to be updated.  The browser makes a request to a server for a page.  Play receives that request, renders a page and sends it to the browser.  The browser then renders that page.  Any update in state on the server won't be reflected in the browser unless the browser makes another request to get that.

If you want updates on the server side to be reflected immediately in the browser, then you need to set up some form of event stream from the server to the browser, that the browser can then react to.  This is often done using WebSockets, but it means on the server side, you need to send an event down the browsers WebSocket every time something changes - you can't expect changing a variable to trigger that.  Then you have to implement a JavaScript app on the browser side that receives those events, and updates the UI accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Play renders the view **every time** (exactly at *every request*), unless you are using some kind of caching. It may be built-in Play's cache system or maybe some persistence layer cache which keeps the views unchanged, but there;s no way to guess within your question.